# Review-beta doesn't handle captcha and show an undefined box

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, captcha

Since few days I made some edits on SO and sometimes I got a captcha.

But when I want to improve a suggested-edit, edit a vote-closed question or improve a low-quality answer/question I got an `undefined` box when hitting the `Save Edits` button:

[image]

As you can see, the response want to redirect me to the captcha.

Comment: I had the undefined without a captcha only once a few days before and never again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now (thanks for the helpful screenshot!). In the event that your edit requires a CAPTCHA, you'll be redirected to the CAPTCHA page, and then back to the review page upon completion.

Comment: Just got one and the redirection works fine, thanks !